# performance of my application using wampserver

Tags: php, ajax, performance, wampserver, xajax

I have developed an application using php, mysql and xajax. I always used to test on a setup of which I had installed all applications seperately (apache, php and mysql) and my application was fast (by this I mean that the responsetime of useraction were very low).

I recently removed apache, php and mysql and installed wampserver. From that point on the responsetimes of useractions have increased significantly (tripled). Does anybody have similar experiences? I use the out-of-the-box settings for wampserver and have installed wampserver on both my main computer (Vista) and my laptop (XP).

Any suggestions would be helpfull. I love the idea of a one package deal for php, apache and mysql but if this means that performance goes down I think I would rather revert back to my old setup without wamp.

Thanks,
Jasper

Comment: I currently use WAMP on my XP machine. Have never had a problem with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, no slow down on XAMPP/WAMP.
it should not be that slow: because it's your own computer.

do some actual timing and get real figures. it might be your loopback adapter, network, browser and so on.

to do actual script timing do the following

add the following to the start of your script

```
function microtime_float(){
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}
$time_start = microtime_float();
```

At the end of your script, add the following:

```
$time_end = microtime_float();
$loadedin = (float)($time_end - $time_start);
echo $loadedin.' s<br/>';
```

Then when you load the page, at the end of your age, it will display the time in seconds taken to load the whole script.

Comment: Thanks Mauris, I added some timings but it turned out that all my xajax and php calls are fast (<200ms). I removed wamp from my system and installed php, mysql and apache seperately. It's all much faster now...

Comment: that's awesome. all the best!

Answer (score 1):

I've never noticed a slowdown with WAMP (compared to my server that has them installed separately).
You may be able to fix it by changing something in the Apache, PHP or MySQL configuration. I'd compare what you have now to what it was set up like earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I would compare the config files, as there are probably small config changes that could have big affects on Apache, MySQL or PHP.